# What would the output of a 7447 IC be if the input was above 9?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Since the input is four binary digits, the input could conceivably range from 0 to 15. If you had an input of, say 2 and 8, would you get hex, would you get a meaningless output, or would it not output at all?

We used this, along with a 7490 and a 7404 outputted to a 7 segment display for a intro to engineering lab, but we were not able to make the output meaningful, and I'm still confused as to what the output meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your 7447 and 7490 mixed up. The 7490 is the decade counter. The 7447 is a "BCD-TO-SEVEN-SEGMENT DECODER/DRIVER". Here is the [datasheet for 7447](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/sdls111-103480.pdf). If you look on page 3 you will see a diagram of the segment outputs for binary inputs above 9.

Comment: You're right, I accidentally called the 7447 a decade counter. I was asking about the function of a 7447 though.

Answer (score 1):

When [designing a circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87876/is-there-a-better-way-to-plan-a-circuit-to-square-a-3-bits-binary-number) for use with a limited range (as opposed to the [universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_%28mathematics%29) of all values with a certain number of bits), values outside of that range are ignored. This results in a simpler circuit with the tradeoff that values *outside* the range will likely *never* have any sort of meaningful value.

Comment: Are you saying this is true in general, or you know this to be true of the 7447 chip?

Comment: @Jack: This is true in general. The 7447 is merely the first one you've run across and looked at closely.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I wouldn't say it's "true in general"; though values outside the range are *often* ignored in design, many designs endeavor to ensure some level of reasonable behavior.  For example, devices whose state can be set to an invalid value will often explicitly specify that undocumented states will within a specified number steps transition into a documented state [the documentation may or may not specify which one].  The designers of the popular 6502 processor don't seem to have considered such issues, since there are some undocumented instructions that...

Comment: ...do wonderful and useful things (e.g. load both the accumulator and X register from memory, or decrement a value in memory and compare the result to the value in the accumulator), but some others will cause the processor's instruction sequencer to fall into an invalid state which can only be recovered via reset (even an NMI won't help).